# Create keyboard event UEFI

Tags: c, uefi

I'm quite new to the UEFI world, and I was wondering if I can create a event that simulates a key press.

For instance, I have a timer event like this:

```
Status = gBS->CreateEvent(EVT_TIMER, TPL_CALLBACK, NULL, NULL, &Events[1]);
Status = gBS->SetTimer(Events[1], TimerPeriodic, 10 * 1000 * 1000);
Status = gBS->WaitForEvent (2, Events, &EventIndex);

if (EFI_SUCCESS == Status) {
   if (EventIndex == 1) {
       // key press here
   }
}
```

And then when I get into the second if statement, I would like to have a event that presses the **ENTER** key.

Is that possible ?

Thanks !

Comment: What are you expecting to send a keyboard event to?

Comment: Hi @duskwuff, I actually intend to call another .efi application within this first application, and then, when it reaches that second if, I would like to do the press event, it will work as a cancel to the second application, thanks for the response !

Comment: You don't need keypress emulation. It'd be a bad practice. Just call the required routine directly when timer goes off. Basically you should have calls to whe same load-application-routine from two places: enter key press handler and timer interrupt handler

Comment: Hi @AlexanderZhak, thanks for replying, unfortunately I don't have that routine since I'm calling the application Y (which contains the call off methods) from the application X (which would emulate the key press) so that the event can be caught on the application Y and then call it off.
I would be "running" two applications at the same time. If UEFI was multi thread it would be a lot easier. :(

Comment: When you run application B from application A, then application A waits until application B finishes. UEFI is not multitasking. Even timer events configured in application A might work incorrectly (I have some PCs with UEFI 2.3 and 2.5 which fail to process timer events configured in app A while app B is executing. Although it works fine in VMWare). What I want to say is your approach is completely wrong. If you want something that reminds multitasking, build drivers and communicate with them from your main thread

Comment: @AlexanderZhak thanks for the response ! Well, I wasn't sure this would work out just fine, but I figured it may be worth the trouble of researching before just build drivers and so on, which will be a much bigger work to do. Anyways, thank you !